# Проблема с вызовом функции

Tags: python, функции, классы, tkinter

понимаю что проблема абсолютно нубская, но увы я таковой и есть. Вопрос такой, имеется окно с полями, при нажатии на кнопку будет вызываться какая-то функция из Action, на данный момент эта функция не может взаимодействовать с полем ввода, так как  пишет что переменная не объявлена, как ее корректно вызвать, что бы например в будущем можно было включать например, отключать и прочие манипуляции, так же обрабатывать введённый текст. Я запутался.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import random
from passGen import passGen


class Action(object):

    def clckd_pass(self):
        res = int(txt.get())
        password = passGen(res)
        ask = messagebox.askokcancel('Пароль', password)
        if ask == True:
            usr.append(password)
            messagebox.showinfo('Пароль сохранен', 'Пароль: ' + password)


class Item(object):

    def window (self, win_title):
        window = Tk()
        window.geometry('700x400')
        window.title(win_title)
        return window

    def field(self, window, row_lbl, position, action):
        super(Item, self).__init__()
        self.row_lbl = row_lbl
        self.position = position
        self.action = action
        lbl = Label(window, text = row_lbl,)
        lbl.grid(column = 0, row = position)
        txt = Entry(window, width = 50, fg="sienna4", bg="wheat1")
        txt.grid(column = 1, row = position)
        btn = Button(window, text ='Save', command = action)
        btn.grid(column = 2, row = position)
        btn = Button(window, text ='Edit', command = action)
        btn.grid(column = 3, row = position)
        lbl_res = Label(window, text = 'Результат')
        lbl_res.grid(column = 4, row = position)
        return txt

usr = []
action = Action()
item = Item()
window_main = item.window('New User')

usr_fname = item.field(window_main, 'Имя: ', 0, action.clckd_pass)
usr_lname = item.field(window_main, 'Фамилия: ', 1, action.clckd_pass)
usr_pass = item.field(window_main, 'Длинна пароля: ', 2, action.clckd_pass)
dept = item.field(window_main, 'Отдел: ', 3, action.clckd_pass)

window_main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Многовато замешательства, но ничего, это всегда так поначалу. Сделайте lbl, txt, btn(почему их два?, второй перезапишет первый)... сделайте атрибутами класса Item, добавив перед ними self. И затем в функции вызовите  item.txt:

```
def clckd_pass(self):
        res = item.txt.get()
```

Это уберет ошибку из вопроса. Лучше к полям ввода прекрепить переменные StringVar(), IntVar(), ну и т.д. и т.п. [Почитайте документацию.](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Второй btn я проморгал случайно, я понимаю что он должен по-другому называться.